# opencv dnn readnet forward returns nan value

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network

i am new to neural networks. i am trying to use opencv for object detection.i am using yolov3 pre trained model for object detection. this code worked fine on my old laptop but recently i started to use new laptop(i5 9th gen). and my old codes(opencv) are not working. the outs=net.forward(output_layers) returns nan value i am using opencv-python 4.5.0 version. i am not able to understand what went wrong. i am adding picture of the code(spyder)[code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2RtD.png) and list of packages in my environment [package in my environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3FNz.png) 
#---------
my code
#---------

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in 
net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))
img = cv2.imread("spiritualeye.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, 
crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
outs=net.forward(output_layers)
print(outs)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#-----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was with my weights file it got corrupted when i transferred my data between laptops. so i had to download the weight files again.