# No detections using cv2 DNN module YoloV4 Tiny

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv

I trained a YoloV4-tiny object detection model using custom dataset, it was working when I tested using the `./darknet` command. Then I used the below script to run the detections using opencv's dnn module, everything is working, but I can see no detections, neither in console nor in output image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import time

net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov4-tiny-obj_last.weights", "yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('toll2.avi')

frameWidth = int(cap.get(3))
frameHeight = int(cap.get(4))

size = (frameWidth, frameHeight)

# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
# out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, size, True)

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
 
ret = True

while ret:

    ret, img = cap.read()

    height, width = img.shape[:2]

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)

    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)

    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            print(detection)
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            if class_id!=0:
                continue
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.3:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)

                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)

    # cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), color, 2)

    # out.write(img)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

cfg:

```
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.00261
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 6000
policy=steps
steps=4800,5400
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-1
groups=2
group_id=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1,-2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -6,-1

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-1
groups=2
group_id=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1,-2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -6,-1

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-1
groups=2
group_id=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1,-2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -6,-1

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

##################################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear



[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
scale_x_y = 1.05
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=0
resize=1.5
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 23

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
scale_x_y = 1.05
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=0
resize=1.5
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6
```

Below is the output of `print(detection)`

```
[nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.]                                                                                           [nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.]                                                                                           [nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.]
.
.
.
```

Using anaconda, below are the list of packages in my working environment:

```
absl-py                   0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       blas                      1.0                         mkl                                                               ca-certificates           2021.7.5             haa95532_1                                                               cachetools                4.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       certifi                   2021.5.30        py37haa95532_0                                                               chardet                   4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       colorama                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0                                                               decorator                 5.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       easydict                  1.9                      pypi_0    pypi                                                       editdistance              0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       efficientnet              1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       essential-generators      1.0                      pypi_0    pypi                                                       fonttools                 4.26.2                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0                                                               gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       google-auth               1.32.1                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       grpcio                    1.38.1                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       hdf5                      1.8.20               hac2f561_1                                                               icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1                                                               icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3                                                               idna                      2.10                     pypi_0    pypi                                                       imageio                   2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       imgaug                    0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       importlib-metadata        4.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       intel-openmp              2021.2.0           haa95532_616                                                               jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2                                                               keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       keras-ocr                 0.8.7                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       kiwisolver                1.3.1            py37hd77b12b_0                                                               libopencv                 3.4.2                h20b85fd_0                                                               libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0                                                               libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0                                                               lxml                      4.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_0                                                               markdown                  3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       matplotlib                3.3.4            py37haa95532_0                                                               matplotlib-base           3.3.4            py37h49ac443_0                                                               mkl                       2021.2.0           haa95532_296                                                               mkl-service               2.3.0            py37h2bbff1b_1                                                               mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py37h277e83a_2                                                               mkl_random                1.2.1            py37hf11a4ad_2                                                               networkx                  2.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       numpy                     1.18.5                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       oauthlib                  3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       olefile                   0.46                     py37_0                                                               openalpr                  1.0                      pypi_0    pypi                                                       opencv                    3.4.2            py37h40b0b35_0                                                               opencv-python             4.1.1.26                 pypi_0    pypi                                                       openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0                                                               opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       pillow                    8.3.1            py37h4fa10fc_0                                                               pip                       21.1.3           py37haa95532_0                                                               protobuf                  3.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       py-opencv                 3.4.2            py37hc319ecb_0                                                               pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       pyclipper                 1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0                                                               pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2                                                               pytesseract               0.3.8                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       python                    3.7.0                hea74fb7_0                                                               python-dateutil           2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0                                                               pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0                                                               requests                  2.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       rsa                       4.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       scikit-image              0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       setuptools                52.0.0           py37haa95532_0                                                               shapely                   1.6.4.post2              pypi_0    pypi                                                       sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0                                                               six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0                                                               sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0                                                               tensorboard               2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       tensorflow                2.3.0rc0                 pypi_0    pypi                                                       termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       tf-estimator-nightly      2.3.0.dev2020062301          pypi_0    pypi                                                   tifffile                  2021.8.8                 pypi_0    pypi                                                       tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0                                                               tornado                   6.1              py37h2bbff1b_0                                                               tqdm                      4.61.2                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       typing-extensions         3.10.0.0                 pypi_0    pypi                                                       urllib3                   1.26.6                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       validators                0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1                                                               vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2                                                               werkzeug                  2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0                                                               wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0                                                               wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi                                                       xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0                                                               zipp                      3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi                                                       zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4                                                               zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

Comment: there is no `prediction` variable in your code. neither a print where the "." lines could come from. You will not see any detections drawn unless you uncomment and fix the `    # cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), color, 2)` but ther could still be a problem with your model or your results ;)

Comment: @Micka sorry it was a typo, it is `print(detection)` although you could still see in the code, it's `print(detection)` but it's okay, other thing, the `. . .` means it is printing the same output as `[nan nan nan nan nan 0. 0.]`, I thought it was obvious, but its okay and if the detections are nan, what could possibly `cv2.rectangle` draw? And talking about the model, everything was working fine when I used the model using `./darknet` command...

Comment: can you try to use `readNetFromDarknet` and test with a pretrained tiny yolo v3? If that works (better), please try to use a pretrained tiny yolo v4. If that still works there might be a problem in your model. Did you use any parameter changes in your training? Did you use any any newer/different layer types conpared to pretrained models?

Comment: @Micka I used this command to train: `!./darknet detector train /content/darknet/data/obj.data /content/darknet/cfg/yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov4/yolov4-tiny.conv.29 -dont_show -map`

Comment: it's more about what you've changed in the cfg file compared to the standard 80 class tiny yolo v4 pretrained network. Since you only have 2 classes trained (according to your print(detection) there are data 7 fields per anchor box bin -> 5 for position, size and objectness, 2 for class scores) it looks like there is a difference. The question is whether you changed anything else and whether opencv can handle/interpret those changes.

Comment: @Micka Yes, I changed the following things: `batches = 6000`, steps to `4800,5400`, classes to `2`, yolo `filters` according to the formula `(classes+5)*3` therefore, `21`. I have also attached my `yolov4-tiny.cfg` file in question. And after the training on colab, it really worked well, but then I changed nothing and just used the opencv dnn code above and now, no detections.

Comment: thx, the config looks ok to me. Which opencv version do you use? Can you try a pretrained tiny yolo v3 with the same code? https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg and https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3-tiny.weights

Comment: @Micka yes it is working with yolov3 weights and cfg, and my OpenCV version is above 4, I also tried with OpenCV version 3.4.2.16, but the same results, no detections. I don't understand, my V4 tiny darknet model is working great but not using this script..?!

Comment: can you try the pretrained v4 as well? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg and https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/download/darknet_yolo_v4_pre/yolov4-tiny.weights

Comment: if you tested darknet and opencv inference on different systems, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045603/opencv-dnn-readnet-forward-returns-nan-value